# ACF and The Events Calendar (Tribe Events), default content in the content editor for every new event created

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF and Events Calendar Plug-ins on Wordpress. I've already set up some custom fields for the events and I display them into events using shortcodes.

I also made a custom HTML that must appear inside every new event created.

I know absolutely nothing about PHP, at the moment my code sets up the default content for events BUT THE PROBLEM IS that the same custom HTML is set as default content also inside pages and articles that are not tribe events of The Events Calendar...

I need something like "If post type is tribe events do this", can anyone help me please?

Here's my PHP code (I put into ***functions.php*** at the very bottom):

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10, 2 );

function my_editor_content( $content, $post ) {

    switch( $post->tribe_events ) {
        /*case 'sources':
            $content = 'your content';
        break;
        case 'stories':
            $content = 'your content';
        break;
        case 'pictures':
            $content = 'your content';
        break;*/
        default:
            $content = '<div class="tribe-events-single-section tribe-events-event-meta primary tribe-clearfix">
                            <div class="tribe-events-meta-group tribe-events-meta-group-details">
                                <dl>
                                    <dt class="tribe-events-start-date-label">Società:</dt>
                                    <dd><abbr class="tribe-events-abbr tribe-events-start-date published dtstart"> [acf field="societa"] </abbr></dd>
                                </dl>

                                <dl>
                                    <dt class="tribe-events-start-time-label">Tipo di gara:</dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        <div class="tribe-events-abbr tribe-events-start-time published dtstart">[acf field="tipo_di_gara"]</div>
                                    </dd>
                                </dl>

                                <dl>
                                    <dt class="tribe-events-start-time-label">Categoria:</dt>
                                    <dd>
                                        <div class="tribe-events-abbr tribe-events-start-time published dtstart">[acf field="categoria"]</div>
                                    </dd>
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                            <p class="pr2 pl2 text-justify">[acf field="testo"]</p>
                        </div>';
        break;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I just pasted the HTML before the content into single-event.php inside the src/views folder